# How to draw rectangle on a YUV420p frame

Tags: opencv

I would like to draw a red rectangle using the following function on a YUV420P frame. Following code alters the frame and I can see two black line(top and bottom) remaining black dots scattered. Any suggestions?

```
void draw_rectangle(uint8_t *frame, int x, int y, 
                    int width, int height,
                    int img_width, int img_height)
{
    cv::Mat frame_yuv;
    int size[2];
    Point pt1, pt2;
    cv::Scalar color = Scalar(255, 0, 0);

    size[0] = img_width + img_width/2;
    size[1] = img_height;
    frame_yuv = cv::Mat(2, size, CV_8UC1, frame);

    pt1.x = x;
    pt1.y = y;
    pt2.x = x + width;
    pt2.y = y + height;

    rectangle(frame_yuv, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0, 0, 255));
}
```

Comment: I guess the problem is with `frame_yuv = cv::Mat(2, size, CV_8UC1, frame);`, as you have mentioned, the `frame` is in YUV format which means that it is a 3 channel matrix, but you are using `CV_8UC1` which stands for single channel matrxi only, changing it to `CV_8UC3` could help you. Before drawing rectangle, see if you can correctly convert `uint8_t *frame` to a `cv::Mat` properly.

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to store a YUV420 frame *"as is"* in an OpenCV Mat. Mats are either 1, 2, 4 or 8 bytes per sample and 1, 3 or 4 channels meaning you can only get multiples of each of those as bytes per pixel, but YUV420 has 1.5 bytes per pixel, or more correctly 6 bytes per 4 pixels. You will need to go to 1 byte per pixel and 3 channels, i.e 8UC3.

Comment: Here is the layout https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#/media/File%3AYuv420.svg Basically the Y channel can be copied straight to a Mat, but the U and V channel need up-sizing by double in X and Y dimensions before being merged into an RGB 8UC3.

Comment: Please provide a frame of data and also give its dimensions.

Comment: I got the code working with following additional steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I got my code working. Steps are given below for reference.

```
frame_yuv = cv::Mat(2, size, CV_8UC3, frame);

cv::Mat C(2,2, CV_8UC3, color);
cv::Mat C_yuv;
cvtColor(C, C_yuv, cv::COLOR_BGR2YUV_I420);

// Set the R, G, B values to C_yuv
// Extract the Y, U, V components to separate Mat's
// Apply rectange first on Y component
// Devide each points pt1, pt2 by 2
// Apply the rectange on U, V
```

No extra copy of the frame is done.

Comment: Well done on getting your code to work and sharing it. Please consider up-voting (multiple) answers that help you in order to motivate people to assist in future.

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't provided any sample data, please use the file kindly provided by @zindarod with dimensions 144x176.

Here is how the YUV data look in memory:

[image]

Notice in the stream along the bottom... all the Y pixels come first. Then all the U pixels but downsampled by a factor of 4. Then all the V pixels, also downsampled by a factor of 4.

I haven't got time to write the code in OpenCV, but I can show you how to make a regular Mat out of it.

**Step 1 - Extract Y channel**

Take the first 144x176 bytes and put them into an 144x176 8UC1 Mat called `Y`.

[image]

**Step 2 - Extract U channel**

Skip the first 144x176 bytes and then take the next 72x88 bytes and put them into another 72x88 8UC1 Mat called U. Resize this Mat to double the width and double the height, i.e. 144x176.

[image]

**Step 3 - Extract the V channel**

Skip the first (144x176) + (88x72) bytes and then take the next 72x88 bytes and put them into another 72x88 8UC1 Mat called V. Resize this Mat to double the width and double the height, i.e. 144x176.

[image]

**Step 4 - Merge**

Take the Y, U, and V Mats and merge them into an 8UC3 Mat:

```
// Now merge the 3 individual channels into 3-band bad boy
auto channels = std::vector<cv::Mat>{Y, U, V};
cv::Mat ThreeBandBoy;
cv::merge(channels, ThreeBandBoy);
```

[image]

---

There is some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49086001/2836621) that does more or less exactly what is needed for Steps 1-3.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading [this YUV image](http://www.sunrayimage.com/download/image_examples/yuv420/tulips_yuv420_prog_planar_qcif.yuv) from file, which is YUV_I420.

```
fstream file;
file.open("yuv_i420.yuv", ios::in | ios::binary);

// size of image in RGB
size_t rows = 144, cols = 176;

if (!file.is_open())
stderr<<"Error opening file"<<endl;
else {
// get total size of file
auto size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0,ios::end);
size = file.tellg() - size;
file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
char *buffer = new char[size];

// read image from file
if (file.read(buffer, size)) {
  // create YUV Mat
  Mat yuv_I420(rows + rows / 2, cols, CV_8UC1, buffer);

  // draw a rectangle on YUV image, keep in mind that the YUV image is a
  // single channel grayscale image, size is different than the BGR image
  rectangle(yuv_I420, Point(10, 10), Point(50, 50), Scalar(255));
  // convert to BGR to check validity
  Mat bgr;
  cvtColor(yuv_I420, bgr, cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_I420);
  cv::imshow("image", bgr);
  cv::waitKey(0);
}

file.close();
delete[] buffer;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is correct. You have increased the rows by 50% to accommodate a quarter of a pixel of U (or 1 down-sampled pixel per 2x2 area) and likewise with V. I *think* you are only drawing the recrangle in one channel, not all 3. I also *think* it will go wrong if you draw in the lower part of the image rather than near the top. I have not down-voted or anything silly, I am just not certain this is correct.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Please run the code with the given file, you'll see that it's correct. As for drawing on a YUV image, I really don't see the purpose. OP will have to draw the rectangle in 5 different positions in the YUV image if he wants to get the color right.

Comment: I'm still not convinced, sorry :-( OP appears to be trying to draw an arbitrarily coloured rectangle with a single call to `rectangle()`. I still don't think you can do that with this code. I think you have to re-layout the data into 8UC3 to do anything sensible.